# Menuitem form field type: show only components

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, joomla-4.x, form-fields-types

I am building an admin side form and placed a Menuitem form field, that is working just fine.

It is showing all the menu entries as expected, but I need it to list only the ones for "components" (i.e. exclude menu entries of type url, alias, etc.).

The documentation ([https://docs.joomla.org/Menuitem_form_field_type]) refers the "menu_type" attribute, but that is for a different purpose - it's for "menu type", not "menu entry type").

Is there a way to this via the "Menuitem form field type", or must I go around it with the "SQL form field type" querying the #__menu table?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `disable` attribute to disable unwanted menu item types:

```
<field
    name="myfield"
    type="menuitem"
    disable="url,heading,separator"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks! The "disable" attribute is not on the documentation - I would never think of it. It's event better than just not having the unwanted types.